# Does $L^p(E)$ with $m(E)<\infty$ with smaller norm preserve the Banach

Tags: lebesgue-measure, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

If $1\leq p < q <\infty$ and $E$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite measure if we consider the space $L^q(E)$ is it a Banach space with the norm $||.||_p$. I know that $L^p$ space is a Banach space with respect to the $p$ norm.

And I know using Holder inequality that $||f||_p \leq ||f||_q (m(E))^{\frac{q-p}{pq}}$ so $E$ has finite measure then $L^q(E) \subset L^p(E)$. I was trying to construct a sequence $f_n \in L^q$ which is Cauchy with respect to the norm $||.||_p$ which does not converge but I could not? Or is that space a Banach space with smaller norm.  I found similar questions but I did not find any counter example the solvers talk about atoms and the open map theorem, I am searching for a Cauchy sequence which diverge. The questions

1)
[Is Lp space complete with this norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794702/is-lp-space-complete-with-this-norm)

2)
[Is $L^{p}$ space with alternate norm Banach?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98889/is-lp-space-with-alternate-norm-banach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Banach then the identity map from $L^{q}$ with $L^{p}$ norm to $L^{q}$ with $L^{q}$ would be continuous by Open Mapping Theorem. So there would be a constant $C$ such that $\|f\|q \leq C \|f\|p$. Take the example $f_n=n^{1/q}I_{(0,1/n)}$ to get a contradiction.
Aliter: if $f\in L^{p}\setminus L^{q}$ then $(fI_{1/n <|f|<n)})$ is a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent.

Comment: The sequence $ f_n $ is converge in $p$ norm, $\int |n^{p/q}| I_{(0,1/n)}=n^{p/q-1} $ which clearly goes to zero?

Comment: @Ameryr Each $f_n$ is in $L^{r}$ for every $r>0$. $\|f_n\|_p \to 0$ but $\|f_n\|_q $ does not tend to $0$ and that is how you get a contradiction. When you have clearly said $1\leq p <q <\infty$ why are you talking about negative exponents?.

Comment: but what am looking for is a sequence which is Cauchy with respect to $||.||_p$ which does not converge ? Banach space is a complete space so to say it is a not a Banach space with the $p$ norm I should find a Cauchy sequence which does not converge but your $f_n$ converges with respect to $p$ norm right?

Comment: To show that $L^{q}$ is not a Banach space w.r.t. $p-$norm I am  not constructing  Cauchy sequence which does not converge. I am using a theorem to prove that this space cannot be complete. Have been asked to construct a Cauchy sequence explicitly? If not you can change your approach to the one I have suggested.

Comment: can you tell me what is that theorem ? open map ?. Or is it possible to construct an Cauchy sequence which does not converge

Comment: Did I not mention Open Mapping Theorem in my answer? Please read my answer with some patience.

Comment: I am looking for an example without using the open map theorem

Comment: I see it is hard to find a sequence because the set has finite measure hence the only why to get unbounded integral value is to have a pole but any positive function dose not lose a pole by rising it to a higher exponent right?

Comment: @Ameryr I have included an example of a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent.